# OS X Lion Automator saving scripts in classic mode?

Tags: applescript, automator, mac-classic

I have an automator application I wrote that uses some basic automator tools and incorporates in some AppleScript, and it saves and runs on my computer correctly (I am running OS X 10.7.5).  I emailed it to a colleague running 10.8.4, and when she tried to open it an error appeared: `You can't open the application "MyApp" because the Classic environment is no longer supported.`  From what I understand classic support dropped in way earlier versions of Mac OS, and I don't understand why it should be giving me errors today, nor why my program written on a Lion machine would save in such an old state.  Could there be a problem with the AppleScripts I am running?  Or with the way I am saving the app?

**EDIT**
I noticed that when I tried downloading the copy I emailed and running it I experienced the same problem on my machine.  It launches fine from my computer, but the version downloaded from my email has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your software may be using Carbon technology which isn't supported anymore

[Apple's Old Carbon API, An Upgrade Path from the Classic API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_%28API%29)

And/or your software may be using Rosetta to translate old Power PC (PPC) code:

[Apple Used to Support Rosetta for Power PC (PPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29)

Comment: My software is just the default automator that comes with my Mac OS version.  Is there any way to check / change this?

Comment: If you email a copy to me, I can look at it.  kaydell@learnbymac.com

Comment: You could try send your colleague the workflow as a workflow file. Have her open it her Automator. I suspect in this form her Automator will either update it or tell her the parts that need updating. If all goes well she can then save it as an app.

Comment: Ok, I saved it originally as an app - is there a way to save it as a workflow from there?

Comment: Yes, you can choose "Convert to..." from the "File" menu and change how any kind of Automator document is saved (At least in Mountain Lion.)  You can also open apps made with Automator using Automator without converting them at all.  Also, emailed me his app and the problem seemed to be that it was emailed without being archived.  When he or she sent it a second time this time being zipped, it worked OK.